Error creating bean with name Service class
I am trying to use Spring Boot and Vaadin in my project. It works fine in IntelliJ IDEA, but when I build it as a jar and run it using java -jar, it throws the following exception:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4894]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

F:\myproj\vatest\out\artifacts\vatest_jar>java -jar vatest.jar  fully.qualified.package.Application

21:51:34.320 [main] INFO ir.ic.vatest.VatestApplication -- Starting VatestApplication using Java 20.0.1 with PID 16832 (F:\myproj\vatest\out\artifacts\vatest_jar\vatest.jar started by S.NAZARI.H.P in F:\myproj\vatest\out\artifacts\vatest_jar)
21:51:34.324 [main] INFO ir.ic.vatest.VatestApplication -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
21:51:34.831 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext -- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'formService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFormRepository' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'ir.ic.vatest.db.FormRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
21:51:34.836 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'formService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFormRepository' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'ir.ic.vatest.db.FormRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:896)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:849)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
        at ir.ic.vatest.VatestApplication.main(VatestApplication.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ir.ic.vatest.db.FormRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:888)

my entity class:
package ir.ic.vatest.db;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Forms {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "from_date")
    private String fromDate;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "to_date")
    private String toDate;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;

repository class:
package ir.ic.vatest.db;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FormRepository extends JpaRepository<Forms, Integer> {
}

service class:
package ir.ic.vatest.db;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;
@Service
public class FormService {

    @Autowired
    private FormRepository formRepository;

    public List<Forms> findAll() {
        return formRepository.findAll();
    }

}

application properties:
vaadin.launch-browser=true
spring.application.name=vatest
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/form
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

application class:
package ir.ic.vatest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class VatestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VatestApplication.class, args);
    }

}

ui class
package ir.ic.vatest.view;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Composite;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import ir.ic.vatest.db.FormService;
import ir.ic.vatest.db.Forms;

@Route(value = "home")
public class HomeView extends Composite<VerticalLayout> {
    private VerticalLayout mainVerticalLayout;

    public HomeView(FormService formService) {
        mainVerticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        List<Forms> formList = formService.findAll();
        Grid<Forms> grid = new Grid<>(Forms.class, false);
        grid.addColumn(Forms::getTitle).setHeader("title");
        grid.addColumn(Forms::getFromDate).setHeader("date");

        grid.setItems(formList);
        mainVerticalLayout.add(grid);
        getContent().add(mainVerticalLayout);

    }
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ir.ic</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>vapro2</name>
    <description>vapro2</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.4.9</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
      <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>


Why are you running java -jar vatest.jar  fully.qualified.package.Application and not with the actual main class from your code? Passing the main class is also not needed, if you are running a fat/boot-jar - so is the jar you are running just the local artefact instead of the bootjar and are the missing classes in other modules and thus missing from your sparse jar?

thank you for your comment. I could solve the problem by: mvn clean package -Pproduction

I think it should be public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { ... }
